# MD5 в Django. Перенос пользователей из старого сайта

Tags: python-3.x, django, криптография

Делаю перенос пользователей из старого PHP сайта на новенький Django. Загвоздка вот в чем, у пользователей пароли были в md5. Django в md5 вроде как тоже умеет, но я что-то явно делаю не так

Скажем был хэш пользователя `e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e`

Я его перенес в Django так: `md5$e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e`

И пробовал даже вот так: `md5$$e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e`

В settings.py добавил:

```
PASSWORD_HASHERS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.MD5PasswordHasher',
)
```

Не работает. Хэш `e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e` сгенерировал самолично, из "пароля" `123456` и сохранил в таблицу `auth_user`:

```
import hashlib
hash_object = hashlib.md5(b'123456')
print(hash_object.hexdigest())
>> e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e
```

После чего я удалил и заново создал суперпользователя с тем-же паролем

Django из `123456` сотворил такой хэш: `md5$rPy8gTw8whLL$5be80da40b081fe50fabe467e1ccba69`

Очевидно, что между двумя долларами лежит соль пароля `rPy8gTw8whLL`:

```
import hashlib
hash_object = hashlib.md5(b'rPy8gTw8whLL123456')
print(hash_object.hexdigest())
>> 5be80da40b081fe50fabe467e1ccba69
```

**Как перенести пароли?** В старом проекте нет никакой соли, только md5-хэши, а Django без соли пароли не воспринимает

Comment: django.contrib.auth.hashers.UnsaltedMD5PasswordHasher

Comment: @andreymal а для `'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2PasswordHasher'` можно также без соли использовать?

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin зачем?

Comment: @andreymal просто интересно, или хотя бы понять как получается соль в django и где она хранится

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin ну можно в исходном коде Django всегда прочитать)

Answer (score 1):

В settings.py нужно было добавить

```
PASSWORD_HASHERS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.UnsaltedMD5PasswordHasher',
)
```

А хэш должен быть с двумя знаками `$`

```
md5$$e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе, @andreymal